# SailsJS: delete parameters from URL before passing to blueprint

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

We are building an application which uses SailsJS for backend and ExtJS for frontend. ExtJS automaitcally appends these parameters to every AJAX request coming from its grid:
_dc=1421519546371&page=1&start=0&limit=25

I need to remove these parameters on the Sails side before they are passed to the blueprint actions, so that I can take advantage of the blueprint REST API. Where would be the best place to remove these parameters? I can think of my NGINX reverse proxy as one option, but I am sure there is a better place within Sails.

Comment: Yes you could use nginx but if one day you descide or someone in your team descide to go for direct access or to go for apache or another reverse proxy i bellive this kind of stuff have to be fixed in your API :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sails the easiest place would be to remove them with a policy.

RemoveParams.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.query._dc) delete req.query._dc
    // ect ....
    next();
};
```

Alternate method using undocumented req.options. I have not used this, but it would seem to work and was recommended in the comments.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    req.options.values.blacklist = ['_dc']
    // or req.options.values.blacklist.push('_dc') ?? 
    next();
};
```

If you so choose you could also add your own middleware to replace / remove them as well.

Comment: I answered something similar on the way to remove some parameters according / removing credentials and stuff like that and i was told by @sgress454 that the best way to delete things in params was in req.options

Comment: Also a good option, and might be better. I'll attempt to edit my answer tomorrow with both options.